# Does LLVM make an exception in its type rules for integer constants?

Tags: integer, llvm

I'm trying to figure out exactly what the rules are for types in LLVM. As I understand it, the general rule is that an operator such as e.g. `add` must take two operands of type T, and return a result also of type T. However, integer constants seem to be an exception to this.

According to https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#simple-constants

> Standard integers (such as ‘4’) are constants of the integer type.

where the word 'integer' links to

> The integer type is a very simple type that simply specifies an arbitrary bit width for the integer type desired. Any bit width from 1 bit to 223(about 8 million) can be specified.

So it doesn't say anything about what width of integer type a given constant ends up with.

Looking at the LLVM source code, it contains a class called APInt, arbitrary precision integer, https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1APInt.html which seems to suggest integer constants are stored as, well, arbitrary precision.

Some experimentation with clang generated this instruction:

```
store i128 -1844674407370955161510, i128* %3, align 16, !tbaa !3
```

which indeed has a 128-bit integer constant written out without any of the special suffixes that C would require to indicate its type.

But integer constants can also be operands of arithmetic operations.

Does that mean that the full type rule is something like 'an operator must take operands of type T, and return a result also of type T, unless one of the operands is an integer constant, in which case it doesn't need to follow that rule'?

**Edit:** Okay, diving a bit further into exactly what the parser does...

`LLLexer.cpp` at line 1121 in the version I'm looking at, this seems to be where it lexes an integer constant token:

```
  // If the next character is a '.', then it is a fp value, otherwise its
  // integer.
  if (CurPtr[0] != '.') {
    if (TokStart[0] == '0' && TokStart[1] == 'x')
      return Lex0x();
    APSIntVal = APSInt(StringRef(TokStart, CurPtr - TokStart));
    return lltok::APSInt;
  }
```

So it's creating an `APSInt` (arbitrary precision signed integer) with no attached bit width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to jrtc27 on IRC, all operands are required to have the type that was specified for the operation, therefore constant operands are considered to have that type.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not make an exception.

The only way to get a constant integer is to call one of the `get()`/`getTrue()`/… functions in [ConstantInt](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html) and you will note that all of them either take a type with an explicit bit width, or have an implicit type (IIRC bool is the only example of that, but I may have forgotten something).

Comment: Right. But then how does that square with the assembly syntax providing constant integer as just a string of digits, with no indication of bit width?

Comment: because the bitwidth is already implied from the operation. After all, you cannot add i32 bit value with, say, 64 bit constant.